# Criterion for a quasi-compact scheme over a field to be geometrically connected

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following proposition is proved in EGA.
Since EGA is somewhat intimidating(and it is written in French), I'm looking for a more readable proof.

**EGA IV-3 (8.4.5)**
Let $X$ be a quasi-compact scheme over a field $k$.
$X$ is geometrically connected if and only if $X\times_k K$ is connected for every finite separable extension field $K$ of $k$.

Comment: This is [Lemma `0387`](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0387) in the Stacks project.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks. I guess you mean Lemma 28.5.11 of the book version.